# Short story that I believe was in Analog years back. Perhaps in the 1970's. It involved an illusionist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story that I believe was in Analog years back. Perhaps in the 1970's. It involved an illusionist who it turned out was a stranded space traveler. He used his people's knowledge of technology to be a stage magician in order to earn enough money to build a way to return home.

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of *[The Flying Sorcerers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Sorcerers)*, a sci-fi comedy by David Gerrold and Larry Niven. It originally appeared in *If* magazine in 1970 as "The Misspelled Magician" (in two parts, each about 35 pages, based on [the info on ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?464)):

> The plot concerns the efforts of an astronaut, known to the natives as "Purple", to escape from a primitive world on which he is stranded and return to his people. The events are seen from the perspective of Lant, one of the natives, who becomes, in the course of the novel, Speaker (chieftain) of his people.
>
> The natives, a fur covered people, believe in magic and the book shows how sufficiently advanced technology would be perceived by a primitive society.

All issues of *Worlds of IF* have been made available via the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ifmagazine?&sort=-date&page=3):

- [May - June 1970 issue](https://archive.org/details/1970-05-06_IF); *The Misspelled Magician* starts at page 74
- [July - August 1970 issue](https://archive.org/details/1970-07-08_IF); *The Misspelled Magician* starts at page 102